# How do I define a function to execute as a command with M-x?

Tags: functions, commands, interactive, m-x

I wish to `M-x my-func` and let my code run. This seems basic but where can I get more documentation about this, if possible inside emacs itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example:

```
(defun hello-world ()
  "Insert \"Hello World!\"."
  (interactive)
  (insert "Hello World!\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between
a
[common function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html)
and
an
[interactive command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html).  The latter is also a function, but with the addition of `(interactive)` to its body.

You can run the latter, but not the former, by binding commands to
keys or calling them by name via `M-x`.  See the elisp manual
links above more more details.

Comment: tell me in more detail , what commands to use

Comment: @Minikute: your question asked about documentation, and this answer provided it.  Please don't ask for documentation if you don't intend to read it.