# What makes an elisp function available with M-x

Tags: functions, commands, interactive

Why some functions in `simple.el` are invokable with `M-x` and some others aren't?
For example I can do `M-x what-line` but I can't do `M-x line-number-at-pos`.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: There are also other duplicates, e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/54602/105.

Comment: See [Defining Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html) in the [Emacs Lisp Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only functions which are declared to be interactive are callable with `M-x`. The declaration is done by putting an `(interactive)` form as the first thing in the body of the function. Like this:

```lisp
(defun an-example ()
  "this is an example function"
  (interactive)
  (insert "42"))
```

There is a lot of other information you should know about interactive functions, so you should type `C-h f` and enter `interactive` to see more help for it.